# Function pointer as struct field in IDA

Tags: ida

I have following function:

```
void __thiscall ParsePackage_v5(package_t *package, stream_t *stream)
{
  (*(*package->stream + 8))(package->stream, package, 4);
}
```

```
.text:0069F5A0 ; void __thiscall ParsePackage_v5(package_t *package, _DWORD stream)
.text:0069F5A0 ParsePackage_5  proc near               ; CODE XREF: ParsePackageHeader+FB↓p
.text:0069F5A0
.text:0069F5A0                 push    ebp
.text:0069F5A1                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:0069F5A3                 sub     esp, 134h
.text:0069F5A9                 push    ebx
.text:0069F5AA                 push    esi
.text:0069F5AB                 push    edi
.text:0069F5AC                 mov     esi, ecx
.text:0069F5AE                 mov     ecx, [esi+4]
.text:0069F5B1                 mov     eax, [ecx]
.text:0069F5B3                 push    4
.text:0069F5B5                 push    esi
.text:0069F5B6                 call    dword ptr [eax+8]
```

`stream_t` defines as:

```
00000000 stream_t        struc ; (sizeof=0x14, align=0x4, mappedto_136)
00000000 unknown         db ?
00000001                 db ? ; undefined
00000002                 db ? ; undefined
00000003                 db ? ; undefined
00000004 hFile           dd ?                    ; offset
00000008 ReadBytes       db ?
00000009                 db ? ; undefined
0000000A                 db ? ; undefined
0000000B                 db ? ; undefined
0000000C field_C         db ?
0000000D                 db ? ; undefined
0000000E                 db ? ; undefined
0000000F                 db ? ; undefined
00000010 field_10        db ?
00000011                 db ? ; undefined
00000012                 db ? ; undefined
00000013                 db ? ; undefined
00000014 stream_t        ends
```

`(*(*package->stream + 8))` supposed to be converted into `package->stream->ReadByte` but it wont. How can i do this properly and declare function pointer as field type of `ReadByte`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem in your example is that the fields are defined as bytes, not dwords. Press <kbd>D</kbd> twice on those fields to turn them into dwords.

The second problem is that the fields don't have proper function pointer types applied to them. Highlight the fields and press <kbd>Y</kbd> to set the type. Enter something like `void (__thiscall *ReadBytes)(stream_t *this, package_t *package, size_t size)` to create a function pointer type.

Comment: Big thanks! Unfortunatelly, now i have `(*(package->stream->unknown + 8))(package->stream, package, 4);` instead of `package->stream->ReadBytes(package->stream, package, 4);` What's the problem?

Comment: Ultimately you're going to need two `struct`s. On the line ending in `-AE`, the code loads the `stream_t` pointer from the `package_t` object. On the next line, it loads `*stream_t` into `eax`, and the call to `[eax+8]` finally takes place on line `-B6`. This is a virtual function call. Your definition of `stream_t` is incorrect; the dword at `+0` needs to be a pointer to a VTable `struct` that contains the function pointers.

Comment: But how can I define vtable structure? Same as `stream_t` but each field is byte size? Then how `(*(package->stream->unknown + 8))` knows that there are function and it needs to be invoked?

Comment: No, it's a separate structure. I can't tell you what the structure looks like because all I have is a few lines of assembly, but you're going to want a struct called something like `stream_t_vtbl` which contains dword-sized members whose types are function pointers. The first element of `stream_t` needs to be a pointer to that structure. As for what the rest of `stream_t` looks like, I have no idea; the code snippet doesn't show any fields other than its VTable pointer at `+0`.

Comment: I figured it out. Big thanks for helping! You saved my nerves :)